The shortcut Alt-Shift-r doesn't work after enter KDE X11
Recently, maybe after once system upgrade, I found that shortcut alt-shift-r doesn't work anymore, in the whole Desktop Environment system, but it works in the tty, enter by pressing ctrl-alt-fn.
I totally have no any clue. Just create issue https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490140, there are two videos there showing situation.
I use Ubuntu 24.04, and newest KDE with plasmashel 5.27.11.
And there is no this problem when use Wayland.
